# Redirect to same page after click in edit button using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a form,when user will submit the form all the submitted data are appearing in a table  below the form.In this table there is a edit option .I want when user will click on that edit option again that form will appear with the all table data for user editing and again user will edit and submit again.

I am explaining my code below.

> views/vendor/vendor_add.html.erb:

```
<div class="block block-themed">
    <div class="block-title">
        <div class="block-options">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-option enable-tooltip" data-toggle="block-collapse" title="Toggle block's content"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
        </div>
            <h4>Vendor Details</h4>
    </div>
    <!--2nd_total_div-->
    <%= form_for :vendor,:url => {:action => "create_vendor" },remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="timeline-container">
            <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Registration No :</div></span>
            <%= f.text_field :reg_no ,:class => "form-control",:id => "reg" %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left" id="dp1" data-date="12-02-2015" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Date &amp; Time :</div></span>
              <%= f.text_field :dat ,:class => "form-control add-on",placeholder:"Date &amp; Time" %>
              </div>
            <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Name :</div></span>
             <%= f.text_field :v_name ,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Name" %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Father Name :</div></span>
              <%= f.text_field :f_name ,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Father Name" %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left" id="dp2" data-date="12-02-2015" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Date of Birth :</div></span>
              <%= f.text_field :dob ,:class => "form-control add-on",placeholder:"Date of Birth" %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Mob. No :</div></span>
               <%= f.text_field :mob_no ,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Mob. No" %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Address :</div></span>
               <%= f.text_field :v_address ,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Address" %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Service Category :</div></span>
              <%= f.select(:s_catagory,options_for_select([['Wood','Wood'],['Puja Samagree','Puja Samagree'],['Sweeper','Sweeper'],['Photo Grapher','Photo Grapher'],['Burning Assistant','Burning Assistant']],selected: "Select Category"),{},{:class => 'form-control'}) %>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="tbpaddingdiv1 text-center">
                <%= f.submit "Submit",:class => "btn btn-success" %>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <!--end_2nd_total_div-->
</div>
<!--end_1st_total_div-->
<div class="block block-themed" id="vendor-total-div" style="display:none;" >
    <div class="block-title">
        <div class="block-options">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-option enable-tooltip active" data-toggle="block-collapse" title="Toggle block's content"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
        </div>
            <h4>Vendor Details</h4>
    </div>
    <!--2nd_total_div-->
    <div id="vendor-div">
      </div
</div>
<!--end_2nd_total_div-->
</div>
```

> views/vendor/create_vendor.js.erb:

```
$("#vendor-total-div").css("display", "block");
$("#vendor-div").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'vendor_output_table' ) %>");
$("#vendor-div").slideDown(350);
```

> controller/vendors_controller.rb:

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
    def vendor_add
        @vendor=Vendor.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end
    end
    def create_vendor
        @vendor=Vendor.new(params[:vendor])
        if @vendor.save
            flash[:notice]="Vendor data has submitted"
            flash[:color]="valid"
        else
            flash[:alert]="Data could not submit"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'vendor_add'
        end
    end
end
```

> views/vendor/_vendor_output_table.html.erb:

```
<div class="block-content" style="display:none;">
        <div class="timeline-container">
          <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                    <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                    <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                    <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                    <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Sl. No</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Date</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Registration No</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Mob. No</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Service Category</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.id %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.dat %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.reg_no %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.v_name %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.mob_no %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.s_catagory %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.id %></td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Check this table,there is a edit option present at last row of table.I need when user will click on that edit option only the form will appear again with all table data for edit and user will edit as well as update it.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create two more method like `vendor_edit` and `vendor_update` in your controller. As simple as you are doing with `new`, `create`, `edit` and `update` methods.

And make update respective changes in your `form`, `routes` etc files.

Comment: @ jon :by creating new,create,edit like process,it will redirect to next page but i need all operation in same(i.e-vendor_add.html.erb) page.

Comment: No you can can write to redirect what ever you want. Or use Ajax call.

Comment: @ jon :Can you please give one small example by taking above code?

Comment: I have already use ajax call for submit form.You can edit the above code for editing the form.